# Microsoft SQL: include dummy row(s) in results when value doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm returning total sales for a period of time for each country.  Sometimes a country will not appear in the results because they haven't had any orders during that time period.  For these countries with no sales, I would like to include in the results the countries abbreviated name and sales total with a value of '0'.  For example, NL and IS should also be included in the results with Sales_Total both with a value of '0'.  How would I include those dummies rows in the results when the country hasn't had any sales for the period?

```
**QUERY:**

SELECT 
    Country,
    SUM(TOTAL) AS Sales_Total   
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY Country


**RESULTS**

Country   Total_Sales
AU        7646
CA        13773
KR        13976
NZ        1831
US        69421


**Required Results:**

Country   Total_Sales
AU        7646
CA        13773
KR        13976
NZ        1831
US        69421
NL        0
IS        0
```

Comment: Do you have a countries table you could outer join from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  SELECT     Country
            , Sales_Total=ISNULL(Sales_Total,0)
    FROM
             (SELECT o.Country
                  , SUM(TOTAL) AS Sales_Total
              FROM   Orders
              WHERE  OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
              GROUP BY Country) AS o
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT DISTINCT
                                Country
                           FROM   Orders) AS C ON o.Country = c.Country;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use (create if needed) a country table you could outer join from.  Then you can write like so;

```
SELECT 
    c.CountryCode,
    SUM(TOTAL) AS Sales_Total   
FROM Country c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    in c.CountryCode = o.Country AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY c.CountryCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Giorgos has one way, but you can also left join your query to the list of Countries that you have in another table (or the same table).  Something like this:

```
SELECT c.Country, ISNULL(s.Sales_Total,0) FROM 
    Countries AS c LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        Country,
        SUM(TOTAL) AS Sales_Total   
    FROM Orders
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
    GROUP BY Country) s 
    ON c.Country = s.Country
```

Answer (score -1):

You can place the predicate of the `WHERE` clause inside `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
    Country,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
               THEN TOTAL 
             ELSE 0
        END) AS Sales_Total   
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: @lad2025 It depends on the actual data set.

Comment: Like fact table in datawarehouse :)

Comment: If there are no orders for a particular country, that country is not going to be shown anyway.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
             THEN TOTAL 
        END) AS Sales_Total` SUM of multiple `NULL` is `NULL`. OP wants zeros.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos still not correct. Please check previous comment.

Comment: @king.code I don't get it: if `OrderDate` is not `BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'` then `CASE` returns 0, so `SUM` also returns 0.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos let's say that the table is empty, the OP still wants to list the countries. So, the correct solution involves a `Country` table.